# How to get current_user's conversations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models as listed below:

Model

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recieved_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "sender_id"
end
```

I tried this in **user.rb**:

```
 def get_user_conversations
    user_conversations = []

    self.recieved_messages.each do |message|
      user_conversations << message.conversation
    end

    self.sent_messages.each do |message|
      user_conversations << message.conversation
    end
  end
```

But I got **messages** instead of **conversations** that I wanted.

And I tried in rails console:

```
u1 = User.first
u1.sent_messages[0].conversation
```

This time got the conversation.

**Here are is my question:**

1. Why does  `user_conversations << message.conversation` not work, but `u1.sent_messages[0].conversation` does?
2. What is the right way to get the conversations at this situation?

Thanks.

---

Maybe this way?

```
ids = current_user.sent_messages.pluck(:conversation_id)

Conversation.find(ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't know, try to reload console. Maybe you should explicitly return `user_conversations` in the end of method.
2. You can use `Conversation.joins(:messages).where("messages.recipient_id = ? OR messages.sender_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id).distinct`

Comment: Yes, that's I want. Thank you, kolas.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
all_conversations = current_user.sent_messages.map { |con| con.conversation }
```

Comment: I tried this, but no lucky. Thank you for your time.